# Compiling Error Sandboxie Open Source v5.40

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, sandbox

Hi I am trying to compile Sandboxie v5.40

I have VS 2015

I have MS Windows Device Driver Kit (DDK) 7.1.0 with Build Environments

I have set some debugging options also symbol modules

I have to compile solution with alphabetical order. they mentioned that in read me , however except 3 solutions

1. KmdUtil 2. SboxSvc 3. SbieDll

these ones must be studied first

but when I come to SboxDrv I got this error

1> process.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp 1> C: \ Users \ dark \ Desktop \ sandboxie-master \ Bin \ Win32 \ SbieDebug \ SbieDrv.sys: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals ===== ===== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I have tried some solutions but still I'm getting this error, whatever I try

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1> process.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp 1>
>   C: \ Users \ dark \ Desktop \ sandboxie-master \ Bin \ Win32 \
>   SbieDebug \ SbieDrv.sys: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Please try this solution:

**Solution**

Copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\vcruntime.lib` into **Additional Dependencies**(Right-click on the project-->`Properties`-->`Linker`-->`Input`-->`Additional Dependencies`)

=====================================

**PS**:

If your **OS** is not win10, you can ignore it.

If your **OS** is win10, I suggest you could [install WDK for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) and then also copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.xxx.0\ucrt\x86\ucrt.lib` into **Additional Dependencies** in case your project uses [CRT Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).

**Update 1**

Please right-click on **SdoxDrv**-->Properties-->Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies.

Input this:

[image]

Then click OK and then right-click on project **SdoxDrv**-->first click  **clean** and then**Build**.

[image]

This will cause any errors in my side.

Comment: I have win10 I have added vcruntime.lib but this time this error pops up


1>process.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
1>C:\Users\dark\Desktop\sandboxie-master\Bin\Win32\SbieDebug\SbieDrv.sys : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: yes I have added them but it was giving same error but I didn't clean it but continued so clean solved my problem but this time Im having "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE346C3E49 (KernelBase.dll) in SbieSvc.exe: 0x00000005: Access is denied". problem at debug or build

Comment: Or you could mark this answer and then create an issue about `visual studio-debugging issue`, and then we  could spend the related time to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: yes I have marked, yes I run it as administrator but still having this problem also I tried regsvr32 KERNELBASE.dll this one and document you have mentioned however Im keep getting "The module "kernelbase.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DIIRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "kernelbase.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again." this error

Comment: For this another scope issue, you can check [this thread](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/kernelbase-dll-crashing-multiple-programs-on-windows-10-x64.2849907/).

Comment: yes I have tried this one a few days ago but doesnt work, to be honest I give up, still thank you for helping